# How to set linestyle to solid/dashed/dotted/ragged/stippled in flash?

Tags: flash

I am using Flash CS4, and it has a feature of drawing solid/dashed/dotted/ragged/stippled lines. But, I can't find API for drawing a line of these styles. [Graphics.lineStyle()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineStyle()) doesn't support it. How can I draw styled lines progammatically?

EDIT: Included ragged/stipple style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manual solution, found [here](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=149841). Works well under AS2, but might require some tweakign to make it work under AS3.

```
var dotWidth:Number = 4;
var spaceBetweenDots:Number = 1;
var totalLineWidth:Number = 250;
var dotsPerLine:Number = totalLineWidth / (dotWidth + spaceBetweenDots);
for (var i:Number = 0; i < dotsPerLine; i++)
{
    var dottedLine:MovieClip = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("topLine_" + i, this.getNextHighestDepth());
    dottedLine.lineStyle(0, 0x000000, 100);
    dottedLine.lineTo(dotWidth, 0);
    dottedLine._x = i * (dotWidth + spaceBetweenDots);
    dottedLine._y = 50;
}
```

You could add a bit random in there to get ragged lines:

```
var dotWidth:Number = 4;
var spaceBetweenDots:Number = 0;
var totalLineWidth:Number = 250;
var dotsPerLine:Number = totalLineWidth / (dotWidth + spaceBetweenDots);
var ragVariance: Number = 2;
for (var i:Number = 0; i < dotsPerLine; i++)
{   
    var raggedLine:MovieClip = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("topLine_" + i, this.getNextHighestDepth());
    raggedLine.lineStyle(0, 0x000000, 100);
    raggedLine.lineTo(dotWidth-random(ragVariance), random(ragVariance));
    raggedLine._x = i * (dotWidth + random(spaceBetweenDots));
    raggedLine._y = 100+random(ragVariance);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it can surely draw dotted and dashed. But how about ragged/stippled?

Comment: ...gave ragged a try. You can specify the amount with the ragVariance variable.

Comment: Thank you, again. I expected APIs for this job, but your approach is also good.