# ActionScript 3.0 Ragged Line

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, line

If I draw a line within the Flash authoring tool I have the possibility to set it's Style to "Ragged".
This does not introduce additional vertices but only changes the way the line is rendered.
is there a way to draw such a "ragged" line using ActionScript 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is unique to the IDE, and is not available via AS3. You may want to look at [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090319/how-to-set-linestyle-to-solid-dashed-dotted-ragged-stippled-in-flash/2090385#2090385), which has an attempt at rendering ragged style via AS3.