# How to draw dashed line in ActionScript 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I want to draw dashed line in Swish Max (ActionScript 2). I use this code but it created a solid red line.

```
_root.createEmptyMovieClip("myclip",1);
myclip.clear();
myclip.lineStyle(2,0xFF0000,100);
myclip.moveTo(100, 100);
myclip.lineTo(200, 200);
```

How to change it to draw a dashed line?

Comment: There's no dashed line style in AS1/2 (actually, I don't think there are any in AS3 either). The most straightforward way to do so is to calculate coordinates for each single dash and draw them in a loop of **moveTo**s and **lineTo**s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set linestyle to solid/dashed/dotted/ragged/stippled in flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090319/how-to-set-linestyle-to-solid-dashed-dotted-ragged-stippled-in-flash)

Answer (score 2):

If you could use AS3, then here's your answer: http://andywoodruff.com/blog/drawing-dashed-lines-with-actionscript-3/
If you have to use AS2, then the idea is as follows: draw a line -> make a gap -> repeat until desired length is achieved. The trick comes when drawing them diagonally, but it's still doable with proper calculations.